# Access the session variables from controller inside ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have certain fields getting filled in my controller.

```
 public string AjaxLogin()
        { 
          //some code to check admin or not
           Session["UserName"] = "Smith";
           if(type="Admin")
           {
              Session["UserRole"] = 1;
           }
           Session["EmployeeID"] = 101;
        }
```

I have an ajax call to this controller like below and if it is success, I need to access these session variables inside success to check the user role.

```
      $.ajax(
             {
                url: GLOBAL.GetAppPath() + 'Home/AjaxLogin',
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',

                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                     console.log(error);
                },

                success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                      if (result == 'OK') 
                      {                          
                        var UserVal = '@Session["UserRole"]';
                        alert(UserVal);
                        if(UserVal ==1)
                        {
                         var baseUrl ="@Url.Action("Admin","AdminPage")";
                        window.location.href = baseUrl;                           
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        var baseUrl ="@Url.Action("Admin","RegularPage")";
                        window.location.href = baseUrl;
                        }
                      }
                     else {
                             $('#msgError').html('Error: ' + result);
                             $('#msgError').css('display', 'block');
                          }
                      },
                  });
```

But I cannot access this variable in this call. I want to check the user role variable and give url actions accordingly.

Comment: Why you dont put the Ajax  success code on controller, and then return the url accordingly?

Comment: @carlosfcmendes : Can you pls show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to a controller in your project you can use the Url helper for you
Sample:

```
return JavaScript( "window.location = '" + Url.Action("Edit","Dispatch") + "'" );
```

P.S: I couldn't comment since it asks for 50 reputation that's why I'm commenting it over here.